# Is there a way to refresh a custom notification depending on day/night mode?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to know is there is a way to change the custom notification when it is already created depending on day/night mode, I mean the custom notification is of white color when it is in notification panel, but when the user changes to night mode from quick settings I want the notification turn to black.